# I've looked at the single-spa site on how to create parcels, I get exceptions

Tags: javascript, micro-frontend

I've been trying to implement single-spa parcels, but I've been getting the following exception

```
index.js:167 Uncaught (in promise) Error: During 'mount', parcel threw an error: 
                  <Parcel /> was not passed a mountParcel prop, nor is it rendered where mountParcel is within the React context.
                  If you are using <Parcel /> within a module that is not a single-spa application, you will need to import mountRootParcel from single-spa and pass it into <Parcel /> as a mountParcel prop   

    at index.js:167
    at index.js:114
```

The error is about a mountParcel attribute of which is passed down the parcel, I've pulled it from single-spa library but still I get the same issue, I've been battling with this problem for a while now, please assist

Please find my code below

parcel-config.js

```
// myParcel.js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import singleSpaReact from 'single-spa-react'

import MyParcelComponent from './my-parcel-component.component';

export const MyParcel = singleSpaReact({
  React,
  ReactDOM,
  rootComponent: MyParcelComponent
})

export function bootstrap(props) {
  return MyParcel.bootstrap(props).then(res => {
    debugger;
  });
}

export function mount(props) {
  return MyParcel.mount(props);
}

export function unmount(props) {
  return MyParcel.unmount(props);
}

// in this case singleSpaReact is taking our inputs and generating an object with the required lifecycles.
```

MyParcelComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class MyParcelComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <h1>This is a parcel</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

single-spa application. attempt to consume the parcel

```
import React from 'react';
import Parcel from 'single-spa-react/parcel'
import * as singleSpa from 'single-spa';

import  { MyParcel } from './parcel1/parcel-config';

export default class Root extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount(){
    console.log(singleSpa);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: '100px' }}>
        This was rendered by app 1, which is written in React.

        <Parcel 
          config={MyParcel}
          mountParcel={singleSpa.mountRootParcel}
          wrapWith="div" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "simple-single-spa-webpack-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple example of how to use webpack with single-spa",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js -p"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/joeldenning/simple-single-spa-webpack-example.git"
  },
  "author": "Joel Denning",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/joeldenning/simple-single-spa-webpack-example/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/joeldenning/simple-single-spa-webpack-example#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.8.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "single-spa": "^3.9.1",
    "single-spa-angular2": "^1.2.0",
    "single-spa-react": "^2.9.0",
    "single-spa-vue": "^1.3.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.16"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why but your code completely works well with below dependencies.  "single-spa": "^4.0.0" and "single-spa-react": "^2.11.0",